# Getting the ID in a list of fragments in a PagerActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a working PagerActivity (extends FragmentActivity) with a bunch of Fragment objects in it. Everything works fine but what I want to do now is to display the number of the Fragment in the list (let's say there are 25 Fragment objects and I want to display the current number in that list of Fragments).

How can I do that? Is there some method I can call in the Fragment object?

I'm filling the PagerAdapter like this (snippet):

```
                fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();

            for (int i = 0; i < wiList.length; i++) {
                WhiteboardImage tmpWi = wiList[i];

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("wiImage", gson.toJson(tmpWi));
                bundle.putInt("positionInList", positionInList);
                bundle.putInt("totalCount", wiList.length);

                fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(params[0], GalleryFragment.class.getName(), bundle));
            }

            mPagerAdapter = new GalleryPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `GalleryPagerAdapter` is a `FragmentViewPager`? Then the number of fragments would be `fragments.size()`, no?